# divide quantity in given group size php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i am trying to divide quantity in given group size using php and its working but not as expected that i want
below is my code to divide into given group size

```
$pakingBoxType = [20,5];
$product['quantity'] = 31;
    $totalQty = $product['quantity'];
    foreach ($pakingBoxType as $key => $value) {
        $arrBoxes[$value] = floor($product['quantity'] / $value);   
        $product['quantity'] = $product['quantity'] % $value;
    }
    if($product['quantity'] > 0) {
        $arrBoxes[end($pakingBoxType)] = $arrBoxes[end($pakingBoxType)] + 1;
    }
```

below is my test case that I want for any of the qty like

```
1) QTY 19 then 1 box of 20
2) qty >10 then 1 box of 20
3) qty 6 then 2 of 5
4) qty 39 then 2 of 20
5) qty 29 then 1 of 20 2 of 5
```

my above code return output when i hve 19 then its show 4 box but it should return only 1 box of 20 qty

pleas help me to fix this issue

Comment: It would return 4 when the packaging size is 5, when you provide product quantity as 19. As from 19 products 3 packages containing 5 each would be possible with remaining 4 products

Answer (score 1):

For reusability you can define a function wrapping the grouping calculations

```php
function groupQuantities(array $packagingSizes, int $quantity) {  
  
  return collect($packagingSizes)->map(function($item) use($quantity){
    
    return [
      'packaging_size' => $item,
      'boxes' => floor($quantity/$item), 
      'remaining' => $quantity % $item
    ];
  })->values()->all();
}
  
groupQuantities([20,5], 31);

//Output
[
     [
       "packaging_size" => 20,
       "boxes" => 1.0,
       "remaining" => 11,
     ],
     [
       "packaging_size" => 5,
       "boxes" => 6.0,
       "remaining" => 1,
     ],
]
```

Function to figure out packaging based on available packaging sizes and quantity of products

```php
function packaging(array $sizes, int $quantity) {
 
  //Don't cconsider any packaging size greater than quantity
  $packs = collect($sizes)->reject(function($item) use($quantity) {
    return $item > $quantity;
  })->sortDesc();
  
  
  if(!$packs->count()) {
    return "Quantity less than the available packaging sizes";
  }
  
  $remaining = 0;
  
  $boxes = [];
  
  do {
    //Get the biggest available packaging
    $size = $packs->first();
    
    array_push($boxes, ['size' => $size, 'qty' => floor($quantity/$size)]);
    $remaining = $quantity % $size;
    
    //Remove the packaging from packs
    $packs->shift();
    
    //reset the available quantity
    $quantity = $remaining;
   
    //Fill the next packaging size if available
    if($packs->count()) {
     array_push($boxes, ['size' => $size, 'qty' => floor($quantity/$size)]);
    }
      
  } while($remaining > $packs->min() && $packs->count());
  
  //Return the results
  return collect(array_m
  return collect(array_merge(
    collect($boxes)->unique('size')->all(),
    [['remaining' => $remaining]]
    ))->all();
  
}

packaging([50, 20, 10,5], 36);

//output
[
     [
       "size" => 20,
       "qty" => 1.0,
     ],
     [
       "size" => 10,
       "qty" => 1.0,
     ],
     [
       "size" => 5,
       "qty" => 1.0,
     ],
     [
       "remaining" => 1,
     ],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

So your conditions can be summed up like this: if the leftover quantity is more than half of the large box, use the large box, else use smaller boxes. Then all you need is an additional condition inside your loop:

```php
foreach ($pakingBoxType as $key => $value) {
    $arrBoxes[$value] = floor($product['quantity'] / $value);
    $product['quantity'] = $product['quantity'] % $value;
    // this is the added part - if remainder is greater than half of the box size
    if ($product['quantity'] > $value / 2) {
        // add another box
        $arrBoxes[$value]++;
        // we've used up all our products, we can declare there's no remainder
        $product['quantity'] = 0;
    }
}
```

Using this, you can delete the part after the loop where you assign the last leftover, since the loop will take care of that:

```php
// this is no longer necessary
if($product['quantity'] > 0) {
    $arrBoxes[end($pakingBoxType)] = $arrBoxes[end($pakingBoxType)] + 1;
}
```

Please note that this solution only works for the sizes specified. If the number of box sizes or the order of the array changes, it won't work. If you need to accommodate different input, then a different algorithm would be required.